# Session variables lost in Popup window?

Tags: php, jquery, session, cookies, laravel

I have a bookmarklet that injects a button on a foreign webpage. When the button is clicked, a popup containing a page from my website appears.

*I am using a PHP framework called Laravel, tested using Chrome browser*

**Problem:** When I check whether the user is logged in from the page originating from my website which is within the popup window, it always returns that the user is not logged in.

```
if( Auth::guest() ) {
    echo "Not logged in";
} else {
    echo "Logged in";
}
```

However, when I visit the same page directly (not within a popup window opened from another website), I can see that I am logged in!

What is the issue here, and how can this be fixed?

---

**Popup JS Code**

```
var popupOptions = 'status=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,personalbar=no,directories=no,location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,width=632,height=295,left=0,top=0';
window.open(' http://www.domain.com/controllername/add?url='+url, '_blank', popupOptions);
```

Comment: Two things, you are not initiating the session in the popup page, or the cookie set for the session was set with a different cookie path say /somefolder/ the session will not be accessible outside of that folder. Check your cookies to see what has been set.

Comment: I see 2 cookies with the same name `laravel_session` set when I'm in the popup window... for `www.domain.com` and `domain.com`. When I'm viewing my website outside the popup window, I only have the cookie set for `domain.com`...

Comment: You could always throw a `print_r($_SESSION)` on the page and see what *is* getting passed.  (It might have something to do with the "referrer" field)

Comment: You shouldn't be having two cookies with the same name. It looks like the popup window is setting another cookie with same name but different domain overwriting the valid one which should be for domain.com. Can you post the code for the popup window?

Comment: Thanks for pointing in the correct direction, I set the `window.open()` to open domain.com instead of www.domain.com and now things are working great! So... is there a way to configure things so the cookie works on both www and non-www urls?

Comment: for it to work for both instances you need to set the cookie with the domain as .domain.com notice the leading '.'

Comment: For a moment I thought you said eat the cookie.

Comment: Works, do you wanna write an answer for the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be having two cookies with the same name. It looks like the popup window is setting another cookie with same name but different domain overwriting the valid one which should be for domain.com